# Naming convention for descriptors

Tags: python, coding-style, naming-conventions

I have a descriptor

```
class ReferredItem(): 
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        ...
```

I use it as decorator:

```
class MyClass():

    @ReferredItem
    some_method(self):
        ...
```

I've seen the decorators are lower case. But classes should be named in camel case.

Should i name the class like `referred_item`? Or leave it as it is now?

Comment: It would most probably be easier to write your decorator as a closure.  This would also make this question obsolete…  (For what it's worth, I'd use `referred_item` in any case.)

Comment: I agree, I think it's more about what you are using it as, so I'd go for ``referred_item`` - there is precedent for this in the standard library - ``itertools.chain`` is a class (with the function ``from_iterable()``), but it's used as a function, so is lowercased.

Comment: @Lattyware: There are many examples: `property`, `abc.abstractproperty`, about everything in `itertools`, ..., as well as the built-in types (`int`, `float`, `dict`, ...).

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer Indeed, I just gave the first example that came to mind.

Comment: If you're using Python 2, use `(object)` instead of `()`; if you're using Python 3, omit `()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) states that

> Almost without exception, class names use the CapWords convention.

without explaining what the exceptions are, but in the standard library, classes that are most commonly used as functions usually follow the function naming convention. E.g. `itertools.groupby` is actually a class, but you don't notice that in ordinary usage; it's an implementation detail and `groupby` could be rewritten as an actual function.

You can adopt a similar style by using the all-lowercase decorator naming convention for classes used as decorators: `referred_item`, not `ReferredItem`.

Answer (score 5):

Although any callable object can be used as a decorator, they are usually thought of as being functions, and function-like objects should follow the "lowercase_with_underscores" convention.

You should hide the fact that your decorator is a class, since this an *implementation detail*.  Consequently, the decorator should follow the "lowercase_with_underscores" style.  That way, you don't have to change user code if someday you decide to implement the decorator as a function.

Personally, I would still use CapWords for the (internal) decorator class name and provide an alias variable that should be used for the decorator:

```
class _ReferredItem:
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        # ...

referred_item = _ReferredItem
```

Comment: Find me a decorator in the standard library which uses snake_case rather than lowercasewithspacesremoved. I can't think of any.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: To name one: [`functools.total_ordering`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)

Comment: Example accepted. I guess I'll let that form live, then. (I know how it is that lots of the standard library uses the lowercasewithspacesremoved form for things that, if they were outside, would have underscores in them, even down to `int` instead of `Int`.)

Answer (score 2):

I usually use CamelCase for the class and then add an alias which I use as decorator.

```
referred_item = ReferredItem
```

Comment: Will you ever use the CamelCase name for it? If not, I don't see why you'd let it exist.

Comment: Sometimes I would. For example in an isinstance call. Also, the name is used in repr.

Answer (score 1):

PEP8 isn't particularly clear on this point… But informally, I've found a good rule is: if a class will be used like a function (ex, as a decorator, but also things like context managers), it should have a lowercase name like functions. This seems to be the convention followed by the standard library.

So I would much rather see `referred_item` than `ReferredItem`.